# PHP test for fatal error

Tags: php, runtime

This is a bit of a long shot, but I figured I'd ask anyway. I have an application that has web-based code editing, like you find on Github, using the ACE editor. The problem is, it is possible to edit code that is within the application itself.

I have managed to detect parse errors before saving the file, which works great, but if the user creates a runtime error, such as `MyClass extends NonExistentClass`, the file passes the parse check, but saves to the filesystem, killing the application.

Is there anyway to test if the new code will cause a runtime error before I save it to the filesystem? Seems completely counter-intuitive, but I figured I'd ask.

Comment: Wow. This is one of the best questions I've seen in this site for a while. I'll be looking forward to an answer myself. Maybe something with `eval()` worth checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly use [`register_shutdown_function`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) to build a JSON object containing information about the fatal error. Then use an AJAX call to test the file; parse the returned value from the call to see if there is an error. (Obviously you could also run the PHP file and parse the JSON object without using AJAX, just thinking about what would be the best from a UX standpoint)

```
function my_shutdown() {
    $error = error_get_last();
    if( $error['type'] == 1 ) {
        echo json_encode($error);
    }
}
register_shutdown_function('my_shutdown');
```

Will output something like

```
{"type":1,"message":"Fatal error message","line":1}
```

Prepend that to the beginning of the test file, then:

```
$.post('/test.php', function(data) {
    var json = $.parseJSON(data);
    if( json.type == 1 ) {
        // Don't allow test file to save?
    }
});
```

Comment: Not tested so no guarantees it would work... I would leave the question open for a while to see what ideas others may have.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly helpful: `php -f <file>` will return a non-zero exit code if there's a runtime error.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps running the code in a separate file first and attach some fixed code on the bottom to check if it evaluates?